# You have an error in your SQL syntax on for the right syntax to use near 'join-date DATE,credit DOUBLE(15,0) zerofill,PRIMARY KEY(id) )' at line

Tags: java, sql, terminal, mariadb, kali-linux

```
create table clients_info (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  join-date DATE,
  credit DOUBLE(15,0) zerofill,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax on for the right syntax to use near 'join-date DATE,credit DOUBLE(15,0) zerofill,PRIMARY KEY(id) )' at line

Comment: Hyphens are not allowed in column names (or other identifiers) unless they are escaped.  Use an underscore (`'_'`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GordonLinoff says hyphens (`-`) are not allowed by default in column names (in *identifiers*). Nevertheless, you can use it if you enclose the identifier in back ticks, as in:

```
create table clients_info (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `join-date` DATE,
  credit DOUBLE(15,0) zerofill,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Or better off, use an underscore (`_`) instead to avoid using back ticks everywhere, as in:

```
create table clients_info (
  id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  join_date DATE,
  credit DOUBLE(15,0) zerofill,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

I personally prefer the latter.